# JQuery Accordion disrupts other page anchor functionality

Tags: joomla, anchor, jquery-ui-accordion

Unfortunately I am using Joomla on localhost and cannot provide a webpage link.

I have a webpage that navigates through the use of smoothscrolling to anchor links.

The menu is fixed on the left and makes use of simple

```
<a href="#wrapper">top</a>
<a href="#section1">section1</a>
<a href="#section2">section2</a>
<a href="#section3">section3</a>
```

My problem occurs when i activate any jQuery accordion extension into any of the sections. 
(i have downloaded and tried them all)

If i place the accordion in section 1, all page jumps except to section 2 & 3 do not work.

If i place the accordion in section 2, the page anchor to section 3 does not work.

I tried removing the return false; to no avail:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
//Set default open/close settings
    jQuery('.xac-container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers
    jQuery('.xac-trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show(); //Add "active" class to first trigger, then show/open the immediate next container

    //On Click
    jQuery('.xac-trigger').click(function(){
        if( jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { //If immediate next container is closed...
            jQuery('.xac-trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); //Remove all "active" state and slide up the immediate next container
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); //Add "active" state to clicked trigger and slide down the immediate next container
        }
        else{
            jQuery('.xac-trigger').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(this).next().slideUp();
        }
      //  return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });

});
```

I saw some CSS tutorials to make the accordion but it create pagejumps for each accordion item that is clicked, and it adds unnecessarily to the browser history.

I hope I am being clear enough. It seemed like it would be a common problem but my lengthy search was fruitless.

Comment: I assume the module embeds a copy of JQuery but does your template also use JQuery? Use a browser extension such as Firebug and see if two JQuery files are being loaded.

Comment: You're an absolute genius! I had 3 different jQuery libraries from smoothscrool, lightbox and the accordion. Removed two of them and everything works perfect! Lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

Right answer from Lodder's comment.

I had loaded multiple jQuery libraries.

Be wary of copy-pasting random code.